# How to extend class on my component class in controller.php

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, controller, class-extensions

I have created a Basic Joomla Component with Component Creator in order to prepare every single files in less the 1 minute :D (I'm lazy, i know.)

I have one view default and one for form edit.

I need to extend the class created by the Component Creator.

I have this controller.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;

/**
 * Class Doclf_usersController
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class Doclf_usersController extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController
{
    /**
     * Method to display a view.
     *
     * @param   boolean $cachable  If true, the view output will be cached
     * @param   mixed   $urlparams An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
     *
     * @return  JController   This object to support chaining.
     *
     * @since    1.5
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
    {
        $app  = Factory::getApplication();
        $view = $app->input->getCmd('view', 'iscrizionelavoratoris');
        $app->input->set('view', $view);

        parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

        return $this;
    }
```

Now i need to extend this class with my custom class, something like this

```
class DivStyle extends Doclf_usersController  {

    private $GetElementRisultato = "document.getElementById('risultato')";
    private $StyleColor = '.style.color =';
    private $Color = '"red"'

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work...
I tried also `extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController`but no win.... 
Error is

0 syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

How can i add my new class extend?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

UPDATED CODE BUT STILL DOESN'T WORK :(

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;

/**
 * Class Doclf_usersController
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */class Doclf_usersController extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController
{
    /**
     * Method to display a view.
     *
     * @param   boolean $cachable  If true, the view output will be cached
     * @param   mixed   $urlparams An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
     *
     * @return  JController   This object to support chaining.
     *
     * @since    1.5
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
    {
        $app  = Factory::getApplication();
        $view = $app->input->getCmd('view', 'iscrizionelavoratoris');
        $app->input->set('view', $view);

        parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

        return $this;
    }

    class DivStyle extends Doclf_usersController {

        private $GetElementRisultato = "document.getElementById('risultato')";
        private $StyleColor = '.style.color =';
        private $Color = '"red"';
    }

    public function checkcodicefiscale() {
        $cf = new CodiceFiscale();
        $app = Factory::getApplication();   
        $input = $app->input;

        $cf ->SetCF($input->get('codice_fiscale', '')); 

        if ($input->exists('codice_fiscale')) {
            if ($cf->GetCodiceValido()) { 
                //Il codice fiscale è valido, procedo a verificare se esiste nel database
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM #__users_dati_anagrafici WHERE cf = '".$input->get('codice_fiscale')."'";
                $result = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObject();

                if ($result >0) {
                    //il codice fiscale esiste, pertanto procedo a bloccare il form
                    echo 'esiste';
                } else {

                }
                //  if($result != null)
                //  {$urlfile = $result->file;}
                //  else
                //  {}

                echo '<script>
                document.getElementById("risultato").style.color = "green";
                document.getElementById("bar_inizio").classList.remove(\'active\');
                document.getElementById("bar_inizio").classList.add(\'done\');
                </script>';

                echo 'Il Codice Fiscale è valido';

                //return valido

                jexit();
            } else {
                echo '<script>
                document.getElementById("risultato").style.color = "red";
                </script>';
                print $cf->GetErrore();
                jexit();
            }


            jexit();
        } else {

        jexit();
        }


    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like you're placing the child class within the parent class like so:

```
class Doclf_usersController extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController
{
    class DivStyle extends Doclf_usersController
    {
    }
}
```

But it should be outside and, ideally, in a separate file.

If you want to keep both classes in the same file for some reason, it should be like this:

```
class Doclf_usersController extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController
{
    // Parent class code.
}

class DivStyle extends Doclf_usersController
{
    // Child class code.
}
```

Comment: THanks for your reply @Sharky but it seems doesn't work.
I return the same error 0 syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: Post your updated code.

Comment: Done! It's at the end of the question

Comment: Your child class is still inside the parent class. I have updated the answer to clarify how to do this. Child class has to be on the same level as parent class, not enclosed in any braces.

Comment: Thanks! But now i have another problem because in the main class i'm call it from task for Ajax request. But let me do some test before update. Thanks for now!

Comment: Works!! Many thanks @Sharky and thanks for help me to learn!